# System.in multiline input, StringIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays, char, java.util.scanner

I am trying to scan a multiline input to be inserted into a 2D array, but I am getting an out-of-bounds exception.

```
int width = 2;
int height = 2;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String theInput = input.nextLine().replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
char[][] arr = new char[width][height];
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        arr[j][i] = theInput.charAt((width*i)+j);
    }
}
```

When prompted for input, I put in the following:

```
AB
CD
//inputted as is
```

Which yields error

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
```

What is happening here? I am removing the newlines so it should be parsed as `ABCD`. Instead inputting `AB\nCD` doesn't even insert correct values into `arr` (it appears as `{A,B,\,n}`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input.nextLine()` reads a single line, without the `\n`. Therefore it only returns "AB". Your calls to `.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "")` have no effect.

You should probably make multiple calls to `input.nextLine` until you get all the inputs you need.

Comment: Is there a method to read multiple lines? The input is copy/pasted from elsewhere directly into the IDE.

Comment: @riista I looked into it. `nextLine()` uses an internal regex pattern to determine the end of a line. You could initialize the Scanner with `new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in), "SomeRegExPattern"));` and then use `next()` instead of `nextLine()` to read the input. This would cause `next()` to read input until it encounters a separator defined by your regex (the default is WHITESPACE). I'm not sure, however, which pattern you should use. How do you determine the end of the input?

Comment: The end of the input is when there are no characters remaining. Whitespace is valid input, as are new lines.